# Unable to remove String from an Array

Tags: java, arrays

I am currently having a little problem removing a string from an array list. Code is as follows:

```
    String selectedCol = req.getParameter("col");
    if (selectedCol != null) {
        ArrayList < String > ar = new ArrayList < String > ();
        String removeColumn = layout.getColumn(selectedCol).getName();
        String layOut = "layout." + key + "." + layout.getName() + ".group";
        List < String > list = Arrays.asList(props.getProp(layOut, null).replace("[", "").replace("]", "").split(","));
        ar.addAll(list);
        ar.removeAll(Arrays.asList(removeColumn));
        props.putString(layOut, ar.toString().trim());
    }
```

so array "ar" populates the following:

> [contact,  created]

I thought it could be the list size which could be incorrect however it shows up with the correct size when I do `ar.size()`

The following variable:

> removeColumn

is populated with "created".

I have tried the following:

```
ar.removeAll(Arrays.asList(removeColumn));
```

and

```
ar.remove(removeColumn);
```

which should result in:

> [contact]

however using removeall or remove did not work. I am trying to achieve this without the need of looping through.

Help?

Comment: Can you please create an [mcve]

Comment: well, I am confused what is happening what is expected?

Comment: does your array really contains the exact string you're triing to remove? If the case is different then this will not work.

Comment: @Nemisis I think you are right. I think the in the array is causing an issue hence why its not removing the string from the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've generated the list from a string by splitting it on `","`, but there are spaces between items in the string, so the two strings in your list are: `"contact"` and `" created"`.

If you must parse a string in this way, change the split regex to `", "`, or if you need it to be more tolerant to sloppy input, `"\\s*,\\s*"`, allowing optional spaces before or after.

Answer (score 0):

Your array elements may have some white spaces. Which is leading to mismatch. You can use “\s*,\s*” in split to get rid of those white spaces. Also use trim() to remove any leading or trailing spaces.

For Example:

```
    List < String > list = Arrays.asList(props.getProp(layOut, null).replace("[", "").replace("]", "").trim().split("\\s*,\\s*"));
```